# Set Field in One Table Equal To Field In Another on Certain Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a DB in SQL Server 2005 that does not have Unique IDs in the all of the tables that I need them in.  My workaround has been to create a another set of somewhat similar tables with enforced unique IDs.

I want now to carry a reference of the new IDs back to the initial set of tables for Join purposes etcetera.  (Aside: these tables are truncated and repopulated regularly, hence the workaround).

In other words: I want to take IDs in Table2 and properly associate with records in Table1.

The difficult piece for me is that records in Table1 are unique only when three fields are considered.

I added an ID field in Table1, and then I tried the following:

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1

SET dbo.Table1.ID = dbo.Table2.ID

WHERE dbo.Table1.foo = dbo.Table2.foo
And dbo.Table1.bar = dbo.Table2.bar
And dbo.Table1.buzz = dbo.Table2.buzz
```

However, I get the following sort of error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "dbo.Table2.foo" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "dbo.Table2.bar" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "dbo.Table2.buzz" could not be bound.
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
UPDATE t
SET id = t2.id
FROM table1 t JOIN 
  table2 t2 ON t.foo = t2.foo AND
    t.bar = t2.bar AND
    t.buzz = t2.buzz
```

[Sample Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed81c/1)

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I'm confused in the shorthand by the difference between t and table1, t2 and table2?

Comment: @user1893148 -- np, those are just aliases for the table name.  Hope this helped!

Comment: @user1893148 -- same as this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75c9c/1 -- just easier to type :) Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You don't make any reference to the table 2 in your query. Try the following :

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1

SET ID = Table2.ID
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table 2 ON
Table1.foo = Table2.foo
And Table1.bar = Table2.bar
And Table1.buzz = Table2.buzz
```

Answer (score 0):

You've found a workaround for your issue but you've created redundant data and denormalized your db, decreasing it's performance.

You said that you didn't have a unique key in the one table.  Then you stated it was difficult for you using three fields that made a row unique, e.g. a unique key. That tells me you're a little foggy on the subject of Composite and Compound keys. I've seen them many times in Oracle systems and it blew my mind the first time I was introduced to the concept.

While they are difficult concepts to understand and work with, they can be very powerful tools in a large normalized environment. I would go brush up on them and look at the "old way" again to see if it makes better sense. Even if the design turns out to be inferior, at least you will have made a well informed design decision.  You can then craft a perm solution.

What was the problem that prevented you from using the composite key?  Is it the complexity?  Stick with it! I'd have to have a pretty serious error in design before I made a new table and added a bag of data to each row returned.  Look into using a view and querying it, whatever you need to do to keep your db normalized.

[Oracle Composite Key](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Composite_key)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_key) (not a lot of info but some)

Comment: [MSDN PRIMARY KEY Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191236(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: The tables are truncated and repopulated without a unique ID every day by a stored procedure. Therefore I've housed unique IDs and the fields necessary to map them in other tables which are permanent. Now it is a part of the stored procedure to check if the records in the daily recreated table already exist in the table with a unique ID, if not it creates one (while pulling in the mapping fields). Then the ids are pulled back into the original table.  This way the ids stay the same for records which reappear in the daily recreated tables. If there is a better way to accomplish this...